# MS Word hindi chart

Tags: ms-word

I work with Microsoft Office Word 2010, and I want to type numbers with Hindi language.
So I go to "Options" and set Numeral to Hindi.
Now I can write hindi numbers ...
But in charts, my numbers don't change to Hindi, and they are still Latin. (I set MS Excel numeral to Hindi too.)

How can I change these??? This is a bad problem!!

Comment: Probably best asked on Superusers.

Comment: [This](http://www.personal.psu.edu/ejp10/blogs/gotunicode/2007/12/generating-arabic-hindi-curly.html) blog post may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround would be to download a Hindi font, say from here: [Hindi Fonts](http://www.kwintessential.co.uk/fonts/hindi/download.html). Paste them in the fonts folder in Control Panel. Restart word. Now, in your chart, select the numbers that you wish to show in Hindi, and select the Hindi font you just downloaded. Use Font2 or Font3 from the given link, and it should do the trick.